# Eliminar comillas (" ") al guardar datos en un txt PHP

Tags: php, archivo, guardar

necesito guardar información en un archivo de texto o un log, pero guando guardo lo que necesito se agregan comillas, punto y coma entre otras cosas ¿Hay alguna manera de evitar que guarde las comillas y todo lo demás que se agrega? 
Mi código en PHP es el siguiente:

```
<?php
  $_POST['result1'];
  $_POST['result'];

  $con = 'Correo: ' . $_POST['result1'] . ' CP: ' . $_POST['result'];
  $file = 'data.log';
  $content = serialize($con);
  $host = gethostname();
  $prev = file_get_contents('data.log');
  file_put_contents($file, $prev . $host . $content . "\n");
  //$content = unserialize(file_get_contents($file));
?>
```

Y lo que me guarda en el archivo es lo siguiente:

```
s:33:"Correo: ajale@jalea.com CP: 12345";
s:35:"Correo: olvvr@jaleosa.com CP: 54321";
s:35:"Correo: jaleosa@jalea.com CP: 09876";
s:33:"Correo: ojolo@joloo.com CP: 10293";
```

Lo que quiero evitar es que agregue lo que está fuera de las comillas, ¿Existe una manera de evitar o eliminar esa parte?

Comment: O sea asi? Correo: ajale@jalea.com CP: 12345

Comment: Sí, sólo quiero guardar lo que está dentro de las comillas, tal cual como dices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No hagas uso de serialize. Esta función va a poner siempre esos datos adicionales.
Por otra parte no hace falta que uses file_get_contents, cuando el archivo sea grande lo estarás cargando entero en memoria para añadir una línea.

```
file_put_contents($file, $prev . $host . $con . "\n", FILE_APPEND);
```

Answer (score 0):

La solución simple, es no ocupar la función  [serialize](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.serialize.php) , y envíe directamente el contenido.

```
 ...
 $content = serialize($con);
 $host = gethostname(); 
 ...
```

Aunque, la función [file_put_contents](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.file-put-contents.php) tiene como tercer parámetro una bandera `FILE_APPEND` para no tener que hacer dos operaciones, un para obtener el contenido anterior y otra para escribir todo, simplemente añadir la información que se desea al contenido existente.

**Ejm Final**

```
$con = 'Correo: ' . $_POST['result1'] . ' CP: ' . $_POST['result'];
$file = 'data.log';
$host = gethostname();
file_put_contents($file, $host . $con . "\n",FILE_APPEND);
```